# Having some problems with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a program that is supposed to calculate your Bmi but no matter what I input the it still saids the BMI is still extremely obese. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me figure out the issue. here is my code:

```js
function CalculateBMI() {

  var ft,
    bmi,
    heighti_e,
    heightf_e,
    weight_e,
    bmi_e,
    bmi;

  heighti_e = document.getElementById("heighti");
  heightf_e = document.getElementById("heightf");
  weight_e = document.getElementById("weight");
  bmi_e = document.getElementById("bmi");

  bmi = (weight_e * 0.45) / (((12 * heightf_e) + heighti_e) * 0.025) ^ 2;

  if (bmi <= 19) {
    bmi = "Underweight";
  } else if (bmi > 19 && bmi <= 25) {
    bmi = "Desirable";
  } else if (bmi > 25 && bmi <= 29) {
    bmi = "Prone to health risks";
  } else if (bmi > 29 && bmi <= 40) {
    bmi = "obese";
  } else (bmi > 40) {
    bmi = "Extremely Obese";
  }
  bmi_e.value = bmi;


  return false;
  
}
```

```html
<form action="" name="bmi" onsubmit="return CalculateBMI()">
  <p>Weight:
    <p/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="weight" name="weight" size="25" />

      <p>Height:</p>
      <input type="text" id="heightf" name="textbox" size="25" />
      <td>
        <p>Ft.</p>
        <input type="text" id="heighti" name="textbox" size="25" />
        <p>In.</p>

        <input type="submit" id="Calculate BMI" name="Calculate BMI" value="Calculate BMI" size="25" />According to the Panel on Energy, Obesity, and Body Weigth Standards published by American Journal of Clinical Nurttrition, your category is:
        <input type="text" id="bmi" name="textbox" size="25" />
</form>
```

Comment: `^` is not exponentiation.

Comment: Please make sure your code sample only contains relevant portions. Links to mp4, descriptions etc. should be trimmed.

Answer (score 0):

Several errors. First, you get elements from HTML, and try to calculate with them; but they are not numbers. They *contain* some text that *represents* numbers. First we need to get the text out of the `input` elements using `.value` property, then we need to convert that string value into a number so that we can calculate correctly using `parseFloat` (or `parseInt` if you don't think you want fractional values for input).

The second error is a syntax error in your conditional structure: after `else` you can't put a condition. If you want to place a condition then you have to do as you have done elsewhere, and place `else if (condition) { ...`, and I have done so below. A better way would be to realise there are no cases when that condition is not satisfied at that point, and simply use `else { ...` (without the condition).

Thirdly, I changed your `^` to `Math.pow`, JavaScript's exponentiation function. `^` has a very different meaning: bitwise XOR.

Also note that I have changed your submit handler to a click handler, and attached it differently. The second point is stylistic: modern JavaScript style guide heavily discourages mixing JavaScript and HTML, and as such JavaScript inside HTML attributes such as `onSubmit` is frowned upon. Attaching functions from JavaScript itself, using `addEventListener` (or an equivalent function if you are using a DOM manipulation library such as jQuery) is vastly preferred.

*However*, the change from `submit` to `click` event is not in any way a correction for you: I simply used `click` because `submit` cannot be used in Stack Overflow executable snippets; in your code, you should probably continue attaching `submit` to your form, and not `click` to your submit button.

```js
function CalculateBMI() {
    var ft,
      bmi,
      heighti_e,
      heightf_e,
      weight_e,
      bmi_e,
      bmi;

    // NOTE: `.value` and `parseFloat`
    heighti_e = parseFloat(document.getElementById("heighti").value);
    heightf_e = parseFloat(document.getElementById("heightf").value);
    weight_e = parseFloat(document.getElementById("weight").value);
    bmi_e = document.getElementById("bmi");

    // NOTE: Math.pow
    bmi = (weight_e * 0.45) / Math.pow(((12 * heightf_e) + heighti_e) * 0.025, 2);

    if (bmi <= 19) {
      bmi = "Underweight";
    } else if (bmi > 19 && bmi <= 25) {
      bmi = "Desirable";
    } else if (bmi > 25 && bmi <= 29) {
      bmi = "Prone to health risks";
    } else if (bmi > 29 && bmi <= 40) {
      bmi = "Obese";
      // NOTE: if
    } else if (bmi > 40) {
      bmi = "Extremely Obese";
    }
    bmi_e.value = bmi;


    return false;

  }
  // needed because Stack Overflow snippets do not allow `submit`:
document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click', CalculateBMI);
```

```html
<!-- removed `onSubmit` because Stack Overflow snippets don't allow `submit` -->
<form action="" name="bmi">
  <p>
    Weight:
    <input type="text" id="weight" name="weight" size="25" />
  </p>

  <p>
    Height:
    <input type="text" id="heightf" name="textbox" size="25" />Ft
    <input type="text" id="heighti" name="textbox" size="25" />In.
  </p>

  <p>
    <input type="submit" id="Calculate BMI" name="Calculate BMI" value="Calculate BMI" size="25" />
  </p>

  <br>According to the Panel on Energy, Obesity, and Body Weigth Standards published by American Journal of Clinical Nurttrition, your category is:
  <input type="text" id="bmi" name="textbox" size="25" />
</form>
```